# I want to mix indoor acrylic enamel paint with indoor acrylic paint

Tags: bathroom

I have interior Beauti-Tone enamel acrylic paint. It cleans up with water it says. And I have Beauti-Tone interior acrylic paint but it's a little too dark. Can I add a tiny bit of the white interior enamel acrylic paint to it to lighten it up a bit?

Comment: You could test it with tiny amounts.  Something like 1/8 teaspoon to a tablespoon.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. White paint is weak at lightening colors. It requires a "large" volume of white to make a real change. Tinting does work well the other way: a small amount of colored paint will tint white paint very easily.